# Odd-one-out chemistry word play

Tags: wordplay, odd-one-out, chemistry

Find the odd one out:

- Onions
- Thioacetone
- Naphthalene
- Cyclobutadiene
- Guanidine
- Cadaverine
- Carbon diselenide
- Benzene

Edit: I forgot Benzene but I added it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it

> [cyclobutadiene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclobutadiene)

because

> It is the only one without a pungent odor, and it is an antiaromatic hydrocarbon.

And

> After searching Wikipedia, all of the other compounds(and onions), are found to have pungent odors.

Comment: Who else could solve this? (maybe riley)

Comment: I meant to add benzene to the list but I forgot, but you more or less got it spot on you just need the word play.

Comment: @QuantumTwinkie drop the prefix and you've got it.

Comment: @QuantumTwinkie not really, think about what I added and think about synonyms (not at the same time)

Comment: Umm, does it have to do with onions, maybe ions?

Comment: @QuantumTwinkie nope. Think about the tags.